# Weird error returned by date_trunc() in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I am encountering the following weird behavior on a Redshift database.

The following query runs as expected truncating the current timestamp to month:

```
select date_trunc('month', now()) -- returns 2019-01-01 00:00:00+00
```

On the contrary this query:

```
select date_trunc('month', now())
from table
```

returns the following error

> ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not
>   supported on Redshift tables.

There is no INFO message but obviously the problem has to do with the `date_trunc()` as it is the only function used.

Normally I would expect that it would work as it does on PostgreSQL, returning the current timestamp truncated to month as many time as the number of rows of the `table`.

I have also taken a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) in case `date_trunc()` wasn't fully supported yet but I cannot find any reference.

Is there anything that I am missing? Any workaround?

Comment: Can you try also selecting one or more columns from your actual table?  I mean, what would be the point of just selecting a constant for every row of your table, and nothing else?

Comment: Yes I have and I am still getting the error. What I was actually trying to do was filtering the rows in order to keep only those where date_trunc('month', created_at) = date_trunc('month', now()) but it didn't work so I tried to understand what goes wrong and I ended up with what I explain at the description of the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

now() is a leader-node only function. that means it works if you don't use a table.

Instead of now() you can use current_timestamp

e.g.

```
select date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
from table;
```

This will work fine.

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html

(right at the bottom)

Comment: Indeed this works perfectly. Thanks for enlightening me